# Draggable and droppable between two divs and sortabble

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-draggable

i,ve been trying to do a drag and drop sort of exercise, and i found this option http://jsfiddle.net/39khs/82/ and http://jsfiddle.net/wj4ak/5/ . However what i need to do is take one div, drag to another and make it take up all the space of that div, and in addition could sort (change order) of the bigger divs. So using these examples i made this http://codepen.io/benasl/pen/ORaVVG?editors=0110 . I tried adding some padding to block div so i can pick it up and sort with other blocks by the corner but that's not exactly what i need.

```
  $(".draggable").draggable({ cursor: "move", revert: "invalid"});
  $(".block").droppable({ accept: ".draggable", 
       drop: function(event, ui) {
                console.log("drop");
               $(this).removeClass("over");
         var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top:0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);               }, 
      over: function(event, elem) {
              $(this).addClass("over");
               console.log("over");
      },
      out: function(event, elem) {
              $(this).removeClass("over");
      }
      });
$("#drop").sortable({ cursor: "move"});
$(".inside").droppable({ accept: ".draggable", drop: function(event, ui) {
                console.log("drop");
         var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);   }});
```

Comment: Your codepen code worked, except you had your JQuery UI include set before your JQUERY include.  Check out this codepen where I reversed them. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgArgy?editors=1010